# How do I write truly custom error messages and codes for Mongoose validation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model

I'm trying to follow the MVC architectural pattern and do all of my validation in my Mongoose model, rather than my controller.

I'm wondering how I can set error codes and truly custom error messages in my model (I.E. without the part that mongoose adds to the beginning of the message.)

At the moment my error message for the name field is: "message": "User validation failed: email: Please enter a valid email address", where it should be "Please enter a valid email address".

The response code from the server was 200 until I changed it in my errorHandlerMiddleware file, which is not ideal as it should be a 400 not the general 500.

So, somebody please help me to set the status code in my model and also make a custom error message.

Many thanks in advance!

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const validator = require("validator");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a name"],
      minLength: [3, "Name must be at least 3 characters"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add an email address"],
      unique: [true, "It looks like you already have an account!"],
      validate: {
        validator: (value) => {
          if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
            throw new Error("Please enter a valid email address");
          }
        },
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a password"],
    },
    tokens: [
      {
        token: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;
  const userObject = user.toObject();

  delete userObject.password;
  delete userObject.tokens;

  return userObject;
};

UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  const user = this;
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "7 days",
  });
  user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token });
  await user.save();
  return token;
};

UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    statusCode(401);
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch) {
    statusCode(401);
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }
  return user;
};

UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (this.password.length < 6) {
    throw new Error("Password must be at least 6 characters");
  }
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 10);

  return next();
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

i need a real custom error code and message from mongoose

Answer (score 0):

I decided to catch the errors in the try/catch block on the controller, as so:

```
try {
  await user.save();
} catch (err) {
  // Error handling for duplicate email address
  if (err.code === 11000) {
    return res.status(400).send("It looks like you already have an account.");
  }

  // Error handling for misc validation errors
  if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send(Object.values(err.errors)[0].message);
  }
}
```